# nginx configuration for reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I am trying to implement reverse proxy using nginx. I am using the below configuration but there is something wrong. 
http://aweuw1tool0211:6405/BOE/CMC using port 80 is not taking up the complete uri but only till http://aweuw1tool0211:6405. Getting 404 error missing web page.

```
server  {
 listen NGX-WEB:80;
 server_name NGX-WEB;
 root html;
 index index.html index.htm;
location /BOE/CMC {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://aweuw1tool0211:6405/;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_cookie_path ~^/BOE/CMC/.*$ /;
```

can someone suggest me what change is required in config file to access 
http://aweuw1tool0211:6405/BOE/CMC using port 80
somehow nginx is taking http://aweuw1tool0211:6405 does not take the webapps

Comment: Your listen line can just be "listen 80;" unless you've specified the server name there again for a good reason.

Answer (score 4):

You've fallen victim to one of the classic blunders of nginx `proxy_pass`: if you put a trailing slash on the URL argument to `proxy_pass`, the original request URI is not passed to the backend.  Drop the trailing slash, and the original request URI will be sent.